# How to generate link to cell containing the same text value as cell in another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet which contains UIDs for a certain range. All of these ranges are copied to another sheet, one below the other. I want to write an appscript, which would generate links to the cells which contain the UIDs in the second sheet, much like using ctrl+F for a particular UID.
[image]
Here, cell A13 contains UID.

[image]
A13 in first sheet contains the same value as G400 in "by rail" sheet.

Is there a way, that we could create a link in cell A13 to "by rail!G400" automatically?
This would help the users to get to the range for later calculations/modifications.

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code, with notes so you can adapt to your data. Remember that some things might need to be edited depending on how you arrange your Google Sheets.

```
function searchAndReplace() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // This will help you get the ID of the spreadsheet, 
  // you can also added manually instead of using ' sheet.getId()'
  let spread_sheet_Id = sheet.getId();

  // Replace 'Sheet1' by the name of the sheet
  let ss = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  // Replace 'A2:A' with the range where the UID is located. 
  let range = ss.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat();

  //This will filter all the empty values in the range
  range = range.filter(function(x){
    return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i++){

    // for all the values in the range it will make a search filter
    // with this we can find the exact location of the cells that match the UID
    // it will return an array of changes including the one in 'Sheet1'
    let search_ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder(range[i]).matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchCase(true).ignoreDiacritics(false)
    .findAll();

    // iterates the range of the search
    search_ranges.forEach(function(search_range){

      // gets the sheet ID 
      // (we will need it to filter data and to build the URL of the cell)
      let sheet_name = search_range.getSheet().getSheetId();

      // filter out the search results for the 'sheet1' 
      //leaving the rest the other ranges where this UID is located
      if (sheet_name != '0'){

        // gets the range for cell 
        let cell_location = search_range.getA1Notation();

        // builds the URL of the cell 
        let cell_URL = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(range[i])
        .setLinkUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spread_sheet_Id + '#gid=' + sheet_name + '&range='+ cell_location)
        .build();

        // Place the URL in the column A starting from A2
        // If you data starts in a different cell
        // you will need to replace the 'i+2' with the new range
        ss.getRange(i+2,1).setRichTextValue(cell_URL)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Once you add the script it will work like this:
[image: example video]

**Reference:**

- [JavaScript For Loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)
- [JavaScript Array forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid)
- [getSheetId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetid)
- [Find and replace text](https://spreadsheet.dev/find-and-replace-google-sheets-textfinder-apps-script#:%7E:text=Sheets%20using%20the-,findAll(),-method)
- [Add links to a cell](https://spreadsheet.dev/add-links-to-a-cell-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script)

---

---

### Update:

1. To exclude "Sheet1" and "UID", I added an extra variable and changed the if statement.
2. For the notification if the UID was not found, I added a new function and a new If statement.

This is the new sample with those changes:

```
function searchAndReplace() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  // This will help you get the ID of the spreadsheet, 
  // you can also added manually instead of using ' sheet.getId()'
  let spread_sheet_Id = sheet.getId();


  // Replace 'Sheet1' by the name of the sheet
  let ss = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');


  // Gets the Sheet ID of the sheet UID 
  let ss_uid = sheet.getSheetByName('UID').getSheetId();


  // Replace 'A2:A' with the range where the UID is located. 
  let range = ss.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat();


  //This will filter all the empty values in the range
  range = range.filter(function(x){
    return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));
  });


  for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i++){


    // for all the values in the range it will make a search filter
    // with this we can find the exact location of the cells that match the UID
    // it will return an array of changes including the one in 'Sheet1'
    let search_ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder(range[i]).matchEntireCell(true)
    .matchCase(true).ignoreDiacritics(false)
    .findAll();
    let trigger = 0


    // iterates the range of the search
    search_ranges.forEach(function(search_range){


      // gets the sheet ID 
      // (we will need it to filter data and to build the URL of the cell)
      let sheet_name = search_range.getSheet().getSheetId();


      // filter out the search results for 'sheet1' and 'UID'  
      //leaving the rest the other ranges where this UID is located
      if (sheet_name != '0' & sheet_name != ss_uid){


        // gets the range for cell 
        let cell_location = search_range.getA1Notation();




        // builds the URL of the cell 
        let cell_URL = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(range[i])
        .setLinkUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spread_sheet_Id + '#gid=' + sheet_name + '&range='+ cell_location)
        .build();
        trigger = 1


        // Place the URL in the column A starting from A2
        // If you data starts in a different cell
        // you will need to replace the 'i+2' with the new range
        ss.getRange(i+2,1).setRichTextValue(cell_URL)
      }
    });


    // adds the trigger if the value is not found in the other sheets. 
    if(trigger == 0){
      no_results(range[i])


    }
  }
}


// Function to create the notification if a UID is not found 
function no_results(value){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();


  // You can change the message in the notification 
  // by changing the text between the "" 
  response = ui.alert("Hmmm... \n We couldn't find any matches for " + value, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

The notification will look like this:
[image: notification]

**New reference:**

- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,ButtonSet))
- [ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set)

Comment: It works wonderfully! Thank you so much Giselle. Is there a way that the search for the UID can be done in multiple spreadsheets? For example, in sheets "by rail" as well as in "by road"?

Comment: You are welcome, about your question it already supposed to do so. However I 'm concerned each cel can only have 1 url, let me do some testing

Comment: I got it. It's best if each cell holds 1 url. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! Let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Is there a way that I can prevent the search from happening to 2 particular sheets called "Sheet1" & "UID"? And is it possible, to let the user know if the search yields 0 results? (i.e., if the UID is not found in any of the other sheets?)

Comment: I updated the answer with the code to excluded `UID` and the notification

Comment: To make this function run every time a new UID is added, should I make the function declaration line like this— “function OnEdit(e){…}”?

Comment: Yes, you will need to change the first function `function searchAndReplace(){...}` to an `OnEdit(e){…}`